# Biblioteca Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe algum lugar onde posso fazer consultas sobre os comandos e funções do Python em Português?

Por ex: Se eu desejar saber informações sobre um comando ou módulo como numpy ou pandas ?

Eu notei que grande parte das informações são em inglês, por exemplo se eu der um help('print') no IDLE ele mostra a documentação da função só que em inglês.

Answer (score 2):

No momento, grande parte das documentações são escritas em inglês. Algumas bibliotecas já possuem iniciatvias para traduzirem a documentação para outros idiomas, veja o Django, por exemplo.

Caso inglês ainda seja uma barreira para você, eu posso sugerir que nas bibliotecas que você busca suporte é:

- buscar por referências em português: autores de livros, fóruns, comunidades ou até mesmo buscar no twitter;
- abrir uma Issue ou reportar que a biblioteca não tem suporte a outros idiomas. talvez esse seja o passo inicial para que passem a considerar e comecem algo nesse sentido
- caso algumas dessas bibliotecas já tenham algum projeto de tradução, veja como você pode colaborar para que o trabalho avance
- na medida do possível incluir, mesmo que autodidata, algum tempo da sua semana para estudar um pouco do inglês. É super ferramental.

Fora isso, não há muito o que ser feito, infelizmente.
Talvez alguma sugestão tenha ficado de fora, mas espero que já te ajude.